# data received from c# to localhost is not shown in localhost webpage - nodemon app crashed

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to pass data from c# using console application to webpage using socket.io in real time

**here is my c# code:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            //String data = Console.ReadLine();
            String data = i.ToString();
            if(data.Equals("exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) break; //If the user types "exit" then quit the program

            SendData("127.0.0.1", 41181, data); //Send data to that host address, on that port, with this 'data' to be sent
            //Note the 41181 port is the same as the one we used in server.bind() in the Javascript file.

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); //Sleep for 50ms
            i++;
        }

    }

    public static void SendData(string host, int destPort, string data)
    {
        IPAddress dest = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0]; //Get the destination IP Address
        IPEndPoint ePoint = new IPEndPoint(dest, destPort);
        byte[] outBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data); //Convert the data to a byte array
        Socket mySocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp); //Create a socket using the same protocols as in the Javascript file (Dgram and Udp)

        mySocket.SendTo(outBuffer, ePoint); //Send the data to the socket

        mySocket.Close(); //Socket use over, time to close it
    }
```

**this is app.js**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');

var mySocket = 0;

app.listen(3000); //Which port are we going to listen to?

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', //Load and display outputs to the index.html file
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Webpage connected'); //Confirmation that the socket has connection to the webpage
  mySocket = socket;
});

//UDP server on 41181
var dgram = require("dgram");
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
  console.log("Broadcasting Message: " + msg); //Display the message coming from the terminal to the command line for debugging
  if (mySocket != 0) {
     mySocket.emit('field', "" + msg);
     mySocket.broadcast.emit('field', "" + msg); //Display the message from the terminal to the webpage
  }
});

server.on("listening", function () {
  var address = server.address(); //IPAddress of the server
  console.log("UDP server listening to " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.bind(41181);
```

**finally this is index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var socket = io();
            socket.on('field', function (data) {

                $("#field").html(data);
            });
        </script>
        Data from C#: <div id="field"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I used [this article](http://frasergreenroyd.com/how-to-use-sockets-to-send-data-from-a-c-application-to-a-serverwebpage/) to implement it, everything, seems work fine for example when I send data to console of node.js it display it but as soon as I run the page (localhost:3000) after several printing "webpage connected" it shows this error in my console:

> nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes

can someone give me a solution?

[this my result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMnx0.png)

Comment: Start listen error even on server and io. Maybe error failing somewhere here.

Comment: can u plz describe more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error may occure on a different levels. I see that you are not listenning socket errors, both for server and io.
Both of them are based on EventEmiter approach, so both have error event to listen.

Try to listen all possible error places, this will give you additional infromation on why your app crashed.

```
server.on("error", err => console.error("server error occured", err));
io.on("error", err => console.error("io error occured", err));
```

**Update**

Replace in index.html script loading for socket.io with this.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>.
```

Then, all re-connection issues should gone. I'm not pretty sure how it is working.

Comment: I put the codes you sent but nothing displayed in console

Comment: did you look at my output picture?

Comment: Yes, of course, and there is no errors that will help to investigate the root of the issue. Do you have same behavior without nodemon?

Comment: let me tell you in a better way.. when I just run the console (app.js) it receive data continuously without any error and shows in console. I mean both c# and app.js works fine. but when I run my html code to display the data in field tag, it return this error after printing some 'Webpage connected' which is in io.on function in app.js. also nothing is shown in my html page.

Comment: Something wrong with socket connection. For a single tab you should see only one "Webpage connected", but instead browser is spamming requests to server, that is not correct. I can assume, that it might lead to some connections limits, that eventually might cause an application crash.

Comment: yeah, I think so.. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: OMG. Replace in index.html script loading for socket.io with this. 
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>. Then, all re-connection issues should gone. I'm not pretty sure how it is working.

Comment: thank you so muchhhh, it's done. every things works fine